# My ubuntu 20.04 system cannot login to graphical desktop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 20.04

When I switch on my Ubuntu laptop, it doesn't take me to the system login page, rather displays a black screen saying:

```
/dev/sda2:clean,xxxxx/xxxxxfiles,xxxxx/xxxxx blocks.
```

Only console <kbd>F2</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> are accessible. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> again takes me to the black screen with the above text and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> freezes the system completely, no keys work then. No desktop is there.

I use nvidia GK107M,[GeForce GT 650M].

Comment: Thanks Simon for the edit.

Comment: What happens when you enter `startx` on one of the consoles?